# Scroll to bottom button behaviour when scroll is 100% bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [jquery-smooth-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-smooth-scroll) for controlling anchor scrolling. There is a feature/option to decide behaviour after scroll. I chose to hide the button after it gets to the bottom anchor. I then implemented some jquery to bring that button back when scroll was no longer 100% at the bottom of the page.

What I am struggling to do is make sure that the button always fades away when scroll is 100% down. The same way a standard back to top works but opposite ends of the page in my case.

Please see this fiddle I have put together https://jsfiddle.net/k253jvt8/

```
/* show and hide button*/
$(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll scroll", function (e) {

  if (document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
    $('.saveForm').fadeIn();
    //below isnt working to fade away .saveform when scroll is 100% bottom
  } else  {
    $('.saveForm').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

The above is the code I use to bring back the button after it disappears, but then cant get it to disappear again when manually scroll to the bottom, it only disappears again when I use the button to get to the bottom - have a play with my fiddle and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Even your fadeIn() seems to not work! It's always visible as I commented out the whole if-else in the function.

Comment: The fade in does work after the button is clicked and scroll is at the bottom, once you start scrolling up it fades in

Comment: Also, i only want to button to dissappear when 100% at the bottom only. it should stay there 99% of the time unless the scroll bar is 100% at the bottom

Comment: I get it now. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, your wrapping `<div class="reportFormPage">` is positioned absolute in relation to the document.

As a result your `<body>` element does not take it in to account when determining its height; hence it always has a height value of 0. Because of this your 'else' condition never occurs.

Removing the `position: absolute;` css rule resolves this issue.

Comment: By removing the absolute the scroll no longer works and the button disappears when at the top of the page and not bottom

Comment: Basically, I always need the button to stay visible unless its at the bottom of the page, it needs to hide when at bottom. At the moment I can only do it after the button has been clicked. I need it to work when manually scrolled to bottom

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bnxzy9kb/ ok so this gets me closer but need the button to stay there all the time unless 100% at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() ==0) {
    $('.saveForm').fadeIn();
  } else if($(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height()) {
    $('.saveForm').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

along with removing `position:absolute` as dommmm has said.

Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sd6sh4v6/2/

See if you like the change I brought to your `smoothScroll` by using no-js fallback.

Comment: No this does not work, the smooth-scroll no longer works. when you click the button in your fiddle it just disappears but does not scroll to the bottom.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I am sorry for the inconvenience caused for the cleanups related to your `smoothScroll`.

Comment: Thanks, no worries. Unfortunately I need the smooth scroll I used and the absolute on the class used